# Generating OAS 3 code for both Spring server and client

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I want to build a Maven module using the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` to generate both server code and client code from two openapi 3 specs. I want the server code to use Spring boot, so I have these settings:

```
<generatorName>spring</generatorName>
<library>spring-boot</library>
```

This works fine and I need `io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations` and `jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api` for OAS 3 annotations and validation.

However, for the client code, I want to use `WebClient` from Spring, the only settings I could find was:

```
<generatorName>java</generatorName>
<library>webclient</library>
```

The client code generates, but the issue is, it requires the older `io.swagger:swagger-annotations` and `javax.validation:validation-api`.

I want to avoid having different sets of libraries. Is there a setting for both the server and client code generations that uses the same set of annotation and validation libraries? Preferably both use `io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations` and `jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62915594/open-api-code-generator-maven-plugin-uses-old-swagger-2-annotations-instead-of-s